# Vector graphic quality quirks

Tags: color, vector, logo

Ok so the logo has a purplish-background-color (`#a11a5c`) and the the logo itself is white.

Is it possible, that these two colors don't get along at all?

The logo size shall be about `250px x 100px` and even though it's using vectors it looks like the quality is garbage (kind of blurry and pixelated in some spots).

When scaled up to far over 500% it's crisp and smooth, just like we would assume vectors to be.

I've also noticed some strange behavior with normal text using these colors. 
So my guess would be that they just don't agree with each other.

Have you guys had any experience with this problem and did you solve it?
Note: I'm not in the position to just change the colors. So some kind of advice would be awesome!

Comment: Welcome Christopher! Realize no one here knows what the logo looks like, what the output is, the final use, the final size, the resolution (if a screen image). A bit more detail may be helpful.

Comment: Can you post the logo?

Comment: Two guesses (though we really need to see an example - not necessarily the logo itself if it's confidential/a draft, maybe a quick knockup that shows the same problem). 1: If the problem is smallish text, it could be **text hinting** ([see this for more details](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6347/)) - if using Illustrator, try save for web art optimised not type optimised, see if that changes things. 2: If it's thin lines, it might be bad anti-aliasing of details that are <1px - try aligning to pixel grid or fattening things up.

Answer (score 1):

`#a11a5c` is dark enough to provide good contrast and sharp edges. From the view point of visual aesthetics, the colors match very nicely too. These are vector paths, nothing special applied:

[image]

If you are having trouble with edge sharpness, you will probably find this helpful:

[How do I get my vector logos to look super sharp on the web?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21455/how-do-i-get-my-vector-logos-to-look-super-sharp-on-the-web)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers and my apologies for not beeing concrete. 
The pic Alph.Dev posted works as an example. Cranking up the resolution to `132ppi` did the trick for some reason. I say "for some reason", because other images looked fine with `72ppi`.